# Using Neural Networks For Time Series Predictions In PHP

Tags: php, neural-network

I'm currently building a website which will aggregate news articles and then categorise them based on their content. However, I would like to analyse the times in which the articles are published so that I can determine if their is some sort of trend occuring, thus allowing me to predict the time when the next article is likely to be published and also eliminating the need to for frequent / unnecessary crawling attempts.

I've had a look on the internet and it seems that neural networks can be used for analysing time series', however I haven't found any examples / code snippets that are benefical or easy for a beginner to understand and then adapt.

These articles also seem to suggest that the inputs to a neural network should either be a 0 or a 1, therefore how would you go about creating a neural network in PHP that has the following inputs i.e. unix timestamps and the capabilitiess to output a single value?

- 1332193520
- 1342194916
- 1342196716
- 1342197376
- 1352197856
- 1362198756

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It would be hard to train a NN in PHP. This should be done offline using some fast non-scripting language. Oh, implementation, training and especially tuning of NNs parameters is not a trivial task.

If I were you I would go for Linear SVMs that outperform other methods for text classification and are quite simple in deployment (and elegant theoretically - Btw, NNs are old fashion). There are excellent implementation of SVMs like 
[SVM Light](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) and [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) written in multiple languages.